# Trying to understand this sentence with a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dereference

I'm trying to understand why do i have this output.

```
a[0]: 5, a[1]: 5, ptr: 5
```

From this little program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[2] = {5, 10};
    int *ptr = a;

    *ptr = *(ptr++);

    printf("a[0]: %d, a[1]: %d, ptr: %d\n", a[0], a[1], *ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

The part that I don't understand is.

```
*ptr = *(ptr++);
```

Because according to me what should happen is that ptr should point to 10, and nothing more, because ++ postfix should increment ptr after the allocation, so according to me this should allocate the value of a[0] to a[0] (which would not affect anything) and after this ptr should be pointing to the 10 on a[1], but what really happens is that at the end a[1] is also 5, can someone explain this to me?.

Comment: well, for me it prints `a[0]: 5, a[1]: 10, ptr: 10`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is undefined behavior. The language does not guarantee whether the LHS is evaluated first or the RHS is evaluated first. A platform can choose which side gets evaluated first.

Looks like in your platform, the RHS is evaluated first.

The value of RHS, is `5`. The side effect is `ptr` to point to `a[1]`.

Then, it is assigned to `*ptr`, which is `a[1]`.

**Caution**
This style of programming is strongly discouraged in the real world since the compiler can do anything it chooses to. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior.

Comment: gcc warns us when you use the right flags `gcc -W -Wall test.c`  `test.c:7: warning: operation on ‘ptr’ may be undefined`

Comment: suggest re-wording the text to clarify that anything can happen (i.e. it's not merely unspecified behaviour) - OP is new and may not be aware of the ramifications of UB